# Changing Tab bar programmatically

Tags: ios, storyboard

[image]

I have created tabbar in storyboard .and i am trying to change default tab bar programmatically using following code.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"TAB"])
    {
        UIStoryboard* storyboard   = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UITabBarController *tabBar = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
        tabBar.selectedViewController = [tabBar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
    }
}
```

But its not working.How i can do it? its not working at all.

Also i want to go back to home view controller when user select first tab.how we can achieve this functionality.

Comment: But its not working.?

Comment: are storyboard and tabBar hold object?

Comment: `prepareForSegue` is called when a segue is just about to be performed.

Answer (score 4):

From the current selected view controller you can change tab selected index using code below.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

To add Tab bar controller to viewcontrollers hirarchy IF YOU ARE USING NAVIGATION AS BASE then you can use:

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard   = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UITabBarController *tabBar = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
        tabBar.selectedViewController = [tabBar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:tabBar animated:BOOL];
```

Answer (score 4):

You can change tab from programmatically:-

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

You can access tab bar's object from storyboard. In storyboard select tabBarController and set storyboard Id. Refer image.

[image]

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard   = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]; //please check your main storyboard name.
UITabBarController *tabBar = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];
tabBar.selectedViewController = [tabBar.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: when i use this code it select the second tabbar item but in actual it shows the content of first view this i am not getting that where is bug?

Comment: Please add viewControllers in your tabBarController.

Comment: i have attached image of my storyboard design.please have a look